# Processing request from basic form

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have problem with processing req that's coming from Post form.

Form looks like that

```
<form action="/" method="POST">

     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="city-input">City name</label>
      <div class="col-10">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" id="city-input" name="map-city">
      </div>
       <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..."/>
       <label style="color: #737373;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;line-height: 30px;">Choose or type</label>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="example-text-input">Symbol</label>
        <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="example-text-input" name="map-symbol">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>          
</form>
```

I try to save each value into a virable

```
router.post('/', jsonParser, function(req, res, next){

 var test = req.body;
 var test0 = test.map-city;
 var test1 = test.map-symbol;

});
```

when I check what is is req.body i get

```
Object{map-city: "downtown", map-symbol: "dt"}
```

how to handle this to save each property to string

Now I get error - ReferenceError: city is not defined

Thank you

Comment: Youre doing test.map *minus* city. You want test["map-city"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dot notation won't work here, because javascript will throw an error if you try to access an object's property with hyphens in it (this is commonly referred to as the kebab case) with dot notation. You should use the bracket notation instead:

```js
var test0 = test['map-city'];
 var test1 = test['map-symbol'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object{map-city: "downtown", map-symbol: "dt"}
```

Change the name property in input tag to `map_city` and it will work.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="city-input" name="map_city">
```

node is understanding your code as test.map subtract with city (`-` is treated as subtraction symbol). Same logic applies to other input fields too.